# Update a data in database using vuex

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vuex

I'm struggling to implement an EDIT_DETAILS feature in vuex but I can implement this without using vuex but I prefer to use vuex because I am practicing my vuex skills.

Below snippets are the code that I am using to make my edit feature work.

> this is in my profile.vue

```
editUser(id) {
      this.id = id;
      let details = {
        id: this.id,
        FULL_NAME: this.personDetails[0].FULL_NAME,
        EMAIL: this.personDetails[0].EMAIL
      };
     //this will pass the details to my actions in vuex
      this.editDetails(details);
}
```

**personDetails**, just retrieves the details of my user in my database.

**id** is the user number which is the primary key of my table in my backend.

below is the example json came from my database

[image: Database]

this is my action in my vuex:

```
async editDetails({ commit }, payload) {
    try {
        const response = await axios.put("http:/localhost:9001/profile/edit/" + payload);
        commit("EDIT_DETAILS", response.data);
    } catch (err) {
        console.log(err);
    }
}
```

and this is my mutation:

```
EDIT_DETAILS(state, detail) {
    state.details.findIndex((param) => param.id === detail);
    let details = state.details
    details.splice(details.indexOf(detail), 1)
    state.details = details.body
}
```

and my state:

```
details: [],
```

Comment: Change the `+` with `,` in the axios request: `axios.put("http:/localhost:9001/profile/edit/", payload);`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Use a comma instead of plus in your axios request
2. Not sure what your response is but this does nothing

```
state.details.findIndex((param) => param.id === detail);
```

3. You need to push into array if not exists